# How can you allow only the database owner and system administrator to use a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms

I am on SQL Server Management Studio 2014. I need to allow me, the database owner and the system administrator to use a database. Also, can both users use the database at the same time?

Comment: Yes, many users can use a database at the same time, that's one of the core capabilities of DBMS. Can you clarify if you're wanting to use Windows authentication or Native SQL logins?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? This seems like something that is very simple to test on your own....  Also your title implies that **only** those two users should be able to use the database. The body of your question asks if those two users can use the database **concurrently**. Please clarify what is your question.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your [database is in single user mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx) multiple users can connect to it.  The default is MULTI-USER which is exactly what it sounds like.  Multiple people can connect as long as they have permission.

Another possibility is that your [instance is in single user mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx).  If this is the case only one connection can be made to the instance at a time.  And obviously only one user will be able to connect to the database.

If as your title implies you want to restrict the user to just admins there is a setting for that.  Restricted_user only allows admins to connect.  Specifically members of db_owner (db level role), or sysadmin/securityadmin (server level role).

For further reading on the access settings for a database look at [ALTER DATABASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx).